# How to set a short/low DbContext CommandTimeout

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

When I try to set a short timeout for CommandTimeout, the operation does exceed the value I've asked it to try to stay under.  For example, when I instantiate, I also set the CommandTimeout.

```
public MyContext(string connString, int? CommandTimeout = null) : base(connString) { base.Database.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout; }
```

Then I subsequently do a simple connection test.

```
    public bool CheckConnection()
    {
        return base.Database.Exists();
    }
```

If the connection is configured correctly, I know it'll be very fast, so when it's not configured correctly, I'd really prefer to set it's timeout very low, like 3 seconds, but it doesn't.  Instead, it returns in the typical 30 seconds to minute span.

How do I limit the connection attempt/timeout to a lower value under which I know a successful connection can be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is with establishing the connection, the `Database.ConnectionTimeout` property is what you're after.  Otherwise, your `CommandTimeout` method should work for long running commands (have you verified the value is actually set via breakpoint or `IDbCommandInterceptor`?)

Comment: Updated; try the `Database.ConnectionTimeout` property

Comment: It returns as an unsuccessful connection after about 8 or 9 seconds after I set the ConnectionTimeout to 1.  Sorry for the red herring with CommandTimeout.  Thanks.

Comment: The additional time is the model buildilng